# CASE statement doesn't work with NA / null value

Tags: sql-server

Columns: CompFreq(nvarchar 255), CompTotal(nvarchar 255)

1. distinct CompFreq has Monthly, Yearly, Weekly, NA.
2. CompTotal has numbers, and NA

I want to convert the monthly and weekly CompTotal(Total Compensation) to yearly, and leave the value as 'NA' if there is 'NA' in the column CompFreq or CompTotal. But I get the following error message.
"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'NA' to data type int."
Any idea to fix it? Thanks!

```
SELECT
    (CASE 
    WHEN CompFreq = 'Monthly' THEN CompTotal * 12
    WHEN CompFreq = 'Weekly' THEN CompTotal * 52
    WHEN CompFreq = 'Yearly' THEN CompTotal
    WHEN CompFreq = 'NA' THEN 'NA'
    WHEN CompTotal = 'NA' THEN 'NA'
    END)
    as YearlyTotalComp
FROM Project_Table
```

Answer (score 3):

A `CASE` **expression** returns a scalar value, and the data type of that data is determined by [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). In your `CASE` expression you have 3 `THEN`s which return a numerical value (an `int`) and 2 that return a `varchar(2)`. As `int` has a higher precedence then the `varchar` is converted to an `int`, and (obviously) `'NA'` is *not* a valid `int` value.

Just omit the `'NA'` values from your `CASE` expression and have `NULL` returned. If you want `'NA'` displayed, handle that in your presentation layer, not the SQL layer:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN CompFreq = 'Monthly' THEN CompTotal * 12
            WHEN CompFreq = 'Weekly' THEN CompTotal * 52
            WHEN CompFreq = 'Yearly' THEN CompTotal
            --Will implicitly return NULL if no WHENs are true
       END AS YearlyTotalComp
FROM dbo.Project_Table;
```

Comment: or cast the numeric values to character.

Comment: I'm not a fan of that, @xQbert . Often numerical values want to be treated as numerical values, and `'10'` and `10` are quite different values (especially when compared to a values like `'2'` and `2` respectively).

Comment: No argument here 10 <> '10' ; but if this going to display and no further processing, which is what I'd expect since we are now returning 'NA' in a numeric data type, I didn't see much harm.  Though it's likely just as easy to in the UI to handle the Null and convert it to NA.  It's mixing Data & presentation but then people pivot data in databases too; when the UI could do it just as easily.  It just "depends" on the use case.  from a purist standpoint, yep don't' mix the data types and handle the NA in the UI,  from a this is quick and dirty and I HAVE to have the NA as a result here...

Comment: Actually, I have also tried this code myself, but it returned with the same error message. Perhaps I should update the column and change 'NA' to 'NULL' ? I'm not sure if that's causing the problem. @Larnu

Comment: *"Actually, I have also tried this code myself, but it returned with the same error message"* If the above is returning the error, then I would suggest that `CompTotal` isn't an `int` and has bad data in it. Time to provide a [mre],, @TacoDumpling .